# Apache grep big log file

Tags: apache, command-line, grep, logging

I need to parse Apache log file to look for specific suspicious patterns (like SQL injections).

For example I'm looking for `id='%20or%201=1;`

I am using grep to check the log file for this pattern (and others) and because these logs are huge it takes a long amount of time

Here my command:

```
grep 'id=' Apache.log | egrep "' or|'%20"
```

Is there a better or a faster method or command I need use to make the search faster?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For starters, you don't need to pipe your `grep` output to `egrep`.  `egrep` provides a superset of `grep`'s regular expression parsing, so you can just do this:

```
egrep "id='( or|%20)'" apache.log
```

Calling `egrep` is identical to calling `grep -E`.

That may get you a little performance increase.  If you can look for fixed strings rather than regular expressions, that might also help.  You can tell grep to look for a fixed string with the `-F` option:

```
grep -F "id='%20or" apache.log
```

But using fixed strings you lose a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I assume most of your time is spent while getting the data from disk (CPU usage is not maxed out). Then you can't optimize a query. You could try to only log the interesting lines in a seperate file though....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `grep -E "id=(' or|'%20)" apache.log` ?